# how to hide div while showing aspx file in diff aspx file

Tags: html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<iframe src="../biceps2.aspx" width="100%" height="250">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to hide some content in div inside biceps2.aspx file
I want to hide some of exercises from this part if the user is beginner or intermediate

Comment: Add some logic to show/hide the divs in the code-behind of the biceps2.aspx page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.